# array of string in a schema mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to have a Role that contains an array of access.

```
access: [{
    type: 'string',
    match: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
    required: true,
    notEmpty: true,
    check: {
        minLength: 2
    }
}]
```

I get:

```
node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:58
    this.caster = new caster(null, castOptions);
                  ^
TypeError: string is not a function
```

If I replace `type: 'string'` by `type: String` it works. Why?
If I try to add an index on the array it doesn't works. (`index: true`)

Do I have to do a `collection.index({'access': 1})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type: String,` is what you want on line 2. Mongoose expects the type to point to a function that can be used to coerce values to the correct type.

Comment: So, basically. When should I use `String` and when use `'string'`?

Comment: Always use `String`, never `'string'`

Comment: So why the official examples use `'string'`? Plus if I write `trim: true` with `String` it doesn't works but works with `'string'`...

Comment: Docs have some of each variety. `var s = new Schema({ name: { type: String, trim: true }})`. I would think both should work but this could  just be a bug or inconsistency. You may have to read the source to find the truth. This is one of many annoying things about mongoose.

Comment: Sounds funny to use. I'm getting lost enough without count bugs... ^^ Well, let's have fun!